# Who is the first Oppai Loli ever featured in anime and manga?

Tags: tropes

The first time I ever saw Oppai Loli is Hestia from *Danmachi*. But, is Hestia the first Oppai Loli in anime and manga? Was there an Oppai Loli before her?

Comment: Did you just coin a term, which abbreviates to OL?

Comment: @Gao:  OL is reserved for office lady, as far as I recall...

Comment: @Gao not really. Hestia was already called Oppai Loli in Danmachi IIRC.

Answer (score 11):

> **Note**: this answer uses the term "loli" as defined by Japanese anime fans: it's either age-related or appearance-related (AniOta), or to the extension of either childlike face, short height, no waist, loli voice, or even deformed (pixiv).

Hestia is *probably* the first character that's called **ロリ巨乳 (*LOLI kyonyuu*, big-breasted loli)** *in-universe*, which is a famous term characterizing her physical trait, but there were many oppai loli before her.

Here are articles on [AniOta Wiki (Japanese)](https://www49.atwiki.jp/aniwotawiki/pages/31324.html), [Nico Nico Pedia (Japanese)](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%83%AD%E3%83%AA%E5%B7%A8%E4%B9%B3) and [pixiv dictionary (Japanese)](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%83%AD%E3%83%AA%E5%B7%A8%E4%B9%B3) that list oppai loli characters with their traits. Here is a [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b2qmxKHIKNmPzVRmOR9OEJH6vWXF-LwYfHtz2HbjMSU/edit?usp=sharing) made by me for compiling a list of oppai loli characters based on those sources.

Based on AniOta Wiki, Nico Nico Pedia, pixiv Dictionary (+ some YouTube videos), [**Saori Kido**](http://saintseiya.wikia.com/wiki/Saori_Kido), a 13-year old girl from *Saint Seiya* (December 1985) is the earliest oppai loli character.

[image: Saori Kido]

<sup>Image courtesy of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athena_(Saint_Seiya))</sup>

Comment: Yuigahama Yui, Kashiwazaki Sena, Kirigaya Suguha doesn't fit the loli part in Oppai Loli. The main requirement of a loli is that she must be short and child-like. Furutani Himawari, Sasaki Chiho and Toudou Kirin can be called loli, although Chiho wasn't so loli-like IMHO. Hestia was definitely called loli. Not sure about the rest.